# If a set is a subset of a larger set, does it make sense to use the word "and" to compare the subset to its parent set?

Tags: terminology

I am wondering, from a formalized mathematical standpoint, if it makes sense to say A **and** B if B is a subset of A.

For example, *machine learning **and** AI* is a common expression in the software industry. AI here refers specifically to *Deep Learning* (in contrast to classical machine learning approaches).

But it is well-established that **deep learning is a **subset** of machine learning**, which is in turn a subset of the over-arching field of AI.

[image]

...which would suggest that it does not makes sense to use the word "and" to compare Machine Learning to AI. In other words, the word "and" suggests machine learning and AI (deep learning) are different things, but they are not, as Deep Learning is a subset of Machine Learning, which is a subset of AI.

Comment: I love oranges and fruits. I say oranges to give you a specific example of a fruit I like.

Comment: Oh I see, from a formal mathematical standpoint,  it doesn't matter, it is redundant, but it is not wrong

Comment: "Oranges and fruits" is nonsensical.

Comment: @Cybernetic No, it's not nonsensical, it's just redundant and silly.

Comment: I don't have to mention oranges cause I said fruits, but I gave oranges as an example

Comment: "like" and "and" are not the same connector.

Comment: Is "and" *ever* okay.  I presume you mean the union and then $A$ "and" $B$ = $A\cup B$ which is equal to $A$.  If $B$ "and" $C$ is ever correct (which I don't think it ever is) then I see nothing wrong with $A$ and $B$ meaning $A$.

Comment: Oh.... or does "and" mean intersection?  What does "mammals and carnivores" mean?  If it *has* a mean applying the same meaning to "carnivores and lions" ought to logically be fine.  "redundant and silly" but fine.

Comment: Now you're not even using the connector "and". The whole point is whether the use of the connector "and" maps to the mathematical definition of sets and subsets, and if so, is it being used correctly when comparing sets and subsets in the English language.

Comment: This is not a mathematical question. And natural language is not a formal language. I’ve voted to close.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

No, in mathematics it is not an accepted idea. If you say $A$ AND $B$ the intersection is expected (provided the intersection make sense).

Comment: If I say I have "oranges and lemons" then you might reasonably assume I have some oranges and I have some lemons, not just the empty intersection between them.

Comment: One thing is language, one thing is mathematics. Set theory is not semantics unfortunately (or luckly?).

Comment: Little of this thread makes any sense, because people are talking about words and phrases out of context. Here for example: "If $A=L^1$ and $B=L^2$ then $A$ and $B$ are Banach spaces". A perfectly acceptable sentence using "A and B" that has nothing to do with $A\cap B$.

Comment: good point, that is completely true.